# Event-based integration with AWS: durability

Tags: change-data-capture, aws

I am trying to build a sync mechanism between Salesforce and AWS using AWS AppFlow(Event based).

But as per salesforce doc, Change Data Capture Events are only retained for 72 hours: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.240.0.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/using_streaming_api_durability.htm

Is there any way we can tackle this somehow that the events are not lost if the problem is not acted before 72 hours?

Comment: Why would you need events to be retained more than 72 hours?

Comment: Aside from the answer to David's question, hopefully by "build a sync mechanism" you mean configuring the [out of the box integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-saas-salesforce.html#eb-saas-salesforce-relay) rather than building your own.

Comment: @identigral Yeah, correct

Comment: @DavidReed I'm thinking of a scenario where lets's say for some reason AppFlow is suspended and is not fixed before 72 hours then we will lose the events during that period of time.

Comment: More or less answered in https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321807/subscribing-to-a-channel-with-an-invalid-replayid . A more complete answer is this: there are a myriad of failure points in a message-oriented solution. These solution trade-offs are first a business decision. For example, if truly needed a lack of durable subscription feature can be worked around by having multiple subscribers and then reconciling missing messages if one sub is down. Mulesoft can be another CDC sub out of the box.

Comment: Business perspective: 72 hours is plenty of time to make sure the subscriber is alive. Thus, your question is an example of a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: So i'm thinking loud, correct me if i'm wrong. We can have Record triggered flow and as part of the flow we can create a record of custom object(Event Log perhaps) and then maybe we can have our custom lifecycle on those records(i don't know if that's possible or not) kind of like our own retention period

Comment: Stick to out of the box stuff.  See [Data Integration](https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/data-integration) and [Event-Driven](https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/event-driven) and [Record-Triggered](https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/trigger-automation) decision guides for recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an Article regarding the [Event Relay in Salesforce](https://www.dreaminforce.com/relay-events-from-salesforce-to-aws-guide/)

In Addition to this, while creating **[Event Relay Config](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventrelayconfig.htm)**, add the parameter `RelayOption` with

`"{\"ReplayRecovery\":\"EARLIEST\"}"`

This will make sure to pick the events that are in Event Bus for 72 hours. I've done this integration myself and let me know if you have any queries.